# find or get map in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, find

i want to know how to name maps, put an id or something to find it later on openlayers, for example:

> div id="map1">
>
> div id="map2">

adition all code to set a map for fill it like:

> map1 = new ol.Map({
>           id: 'Maps 1',
>           target: 'map1' });
>
> map2 = new ol.Map({
>           id: 'Maps 1',
>           target: 'map2' });

then i could find the div for map 1 or 2 with

> mapDiv1 = document.getElementbyId('map1');
>
> mapDiv2 = document.getElementbyId('map2');

but how can i Access the map in mapDiv1 o mapDiv2 ?

also i would like how to do this:

> $.getJSON(theme.url, null, function (data)

but with pure JavaScript, that is couse data only exist inside this function, even if i asign it to a global variable it gets me null, also i don't use jquery or other frameworks just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

> but how can I Access the map in mapDiv1 or mapDiv2 ?

Access can mean many things...

If by "access" you mean *controlling the map*:
Normally you don't use the DOM elements for that. You control the map through your (openlayers) map-objects `map1` and `map2`.

Examples:

```
var baselayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        wrapX:false
    }),
    opacity: 0.7
});
var mpos = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    prefix: 'coordinates: '
});
map1.addLayer(baselayer);
map2.addLayer(baselayer);
map2.addControl(mpos);
```

If "access" ment you want to *get the map as an image*, then see this example: [Export map](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html).

Did you mean something else?

Comment: ok, the second question about $.getJSON i have solved with this code:         > var xhttp;
>        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
>        {
>            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
>            {
>                document.getElementById('tb_ficha').innerHTML == xhttp.responseText;
>                return xhttp;
>            }
>       };
>        xhttp.open("GET", url + feature.getId(), false);
>        xhttp.send();

Comment: about accesing i mean something like if i want to turn on/off visibility on some layers by his name, but i have 2 or more maps, and i don't have a global variable like map1 or map2, i could use some global array maybe to store object maps and find in there the reference, but maybe there could be other way to find a map objetc in mi dom controls ?

Comment: maybe more explain: 
var baselayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        wrapX:false
    }),
    opacity: 0.7
});
var mpos = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    prefix: 'coordinates: '
});
map1.addLayer(baselayer);
map2.addLayer(baselayer);
map2.addControl(mpos);

Comment: a control like:

> <input type="checkbox"  onchange="visible('layer1', this.checked)">

Comment: function:

>function visible(themeId, estatus)
>{
>    var objeto = document.getElementById(themeId);
>    var theme;
>    _map.getLayers().forEach(function (lyr)
>    {
>        if (themeId == lyr.get('id'))
>        {
>            theme = lyr;
>            theme.setVisible(estatus);
>            if (estatus)
>            {
>                objeto.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
>            }
>            else
>            {
>                objeto.style.backgroundColor = "lightcoral";
>            }
>            return;
>        }
>    });
>}

Comment: for visible function i have to make global _map cause i could not know how to tell the check input to send the object map (not the control div map), also i would like to make something like:

> visible(map, themeId, estatus)

where map could be a name for a map or maybe the map object directly.

Comment: i have working code but is a lot to post, but the question is if openlayers have somehow to find a map (other way than using and array of objects), like by accesing a document or dom objects, something like mapCollection.

Comment: I doubt the DOM-element has a (clear) reference back to the map-object. The browser has no notion of maps like it has for forms for example.  I think you'll have to define your own mapCollection array and store your maps there for future reference.